# Specify object in YOLO

Tags: python, yolo

I'm using YOLO for image recognition. I take a picture every half second (because the computer isn't fast enough to use video as an input) and send it to YOLO to detects object. It successfully detects objects in it and write tags on them. However,I want it to raise some flags, like printing out something, when it detects a cat in an image.

Is there a way to specify a certain object (like cat, dog or phone) in YOLO?

Answer (score 0):

If you need only a specific object like a bus you can edit
but there are a lot of  yolo project I am using [moovel](https://github.com/moovel/lab-opendatacam) and the weight file contain only 24 classes the weight file name is yolo-voc.weights so you can give a try 
`[aeroplane
bicycle
bird
boat
bottle
bus
car
cat
chair
cow
diningtable
dog
horse
motorbike
person
pottedplant
sheep
sofa
train
tvmonitor
]`

This is the config.json file you can add this bus or car in `VALID_CLASSES` if you need everything from that class then use `"VALID_CLASSES": ["*"]`

```
{
  "PATH_TO_YOLO_DARKNET" : "/home/nvidia/darknet-net",
  "VALID_CLASSES": ["bus"]
}
```